# How do I print a CSV line from repeated parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala

The sketch of what I am trying to do is below

```
  def printcsv(args: String*) {
    val line = for (arg <- args) {???}
    println(line)
  }
```

I would like

printcsv("Hello", "to", "world")

To print

"Hello","to","world"

I could do this was a lot of imperative contortion however I'm struggling with an elegant solution. It's important to store in val and not simply print directly to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
scala> val args = List("Hello","to","world")
args: List[java.lang.String] = List(Hello, to, world)

scala> val csv = args.mkString(",")
csv: String = Hello,to,world

scala> print(csv)
Hello,to,world
```

If you need quotes in result, you can do something like this before `mkString`:

```
scala> args.map('"'+_+'"')
res14: List[java.lang.String] = List("Hello", "to", "world")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in quotes, use the three-argument version of mkString to do it in one step. No need for a separate `map`:

```
scala> def printcsv(args:String*) = args.mkString("\"","\",\"","\"")
printcsv: (args: String*)String

scala> printcsv("hello", "to", "world")
res0: String = "hello","to","world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just use the mkString method:

```
scala> def printcsv(args:String*) = args.mkString(",")
printcsv: (args: String*)String

scala> printcsv("hello", "to", "world")
res0: String = hello,to,world
```

And if you need any transformations beforehand, you can use the `map` method as om-nom-nom mentioned.